# Get every nth weekday of month periodic in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, datetimeindex

I need to generate an array of dates at specific intervals.  for example every 3 sunday of the month:

```
[2019-02-17, 2019-03-17, 2019-04-21]
```

Is it possible to do this using standard pandas functions?  For example, specifying some particular `freq` field in the `pd.date_range` method or using `pd.Dateoffset`?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
s = pd.date_range('2019-01-01','2019-12-31', freq='D')

s[(s.dayofweek == 6) & (s.day>=15) & (s.day<=21)]
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-01-20', '2019-02-17', '2019-03-17', '2019-04-21',
               '2019-05-19', '2019-06-16', '2019-07-21', '2019-08-18',
               '2019-09-15', '2019-10-20', '2019-11-17', '2019-12-15'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```